# Formula Array returns nothing or just #VALUE! when using Evaluate

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to evaluate Formula array to find a value from sheet with multiple criteria. The sheet name is Holiday_master

So in another sheet `Temp_data` I tried to exceute the following code to set that value in that cell using formula array

```
Public Function getCostMultiplier(dt As Date, wt As String) As Double   'dt is the date of entry, wt working time name "India Full Time","Singapore f........


        Dim lRow As Integer
        Dim we As Boolean
        we = IsWeekend(dt)
        Dim nhRange As Range
        Dim d As Double
        d = CDbl(dt)
        Dim location As String


        Select Case LCase(Trim(wt))
            Case "india full time 45"
                location = "INDIA"
            Case "singapore full time 40"
                location = "SINGAPORE"
            Case "uk full time 40"
                location = "UK"
        End Select

      Dim n As Integer
      'n = Application.Evaluate()
    lRow = Sheets("Holiday_master").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim formula As String
    Dim s As String
    s = Application.Evaluate("RC11")


    formula = printf("{=INDEX( Holiday_master!R2C3:R{0}C3,MATCH(1,(""{1}""=Holiday_master!R2C2:R{0}C2)*({2}=Holiday_master!R2C1:R{0}C1),0),1)}", lRow, location, d)
    ''''INDEX( Holiday_master!R2C3:R11C3,MATCH(1,("INDIA"=Holiday_master!R2C2:R11C2)*(43126=Holiday_master!R2C1:R11C1),0),1)
    n = Application.Evaluate(formula)

    getCostMultiplier = n

End Function


Public Function printf(mask As String, ParamArray tokens()) As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
    mask = Replace$(mask, "{" & i & "}", tokens(i))
Next
printf = mask
End Function
```

So in Temp_data sheet in a cell I set the formula as `getCostMultiplier(RC11,RC4)', so obviously it reaches my function with parameters`26-01-2018`and`INDIA`

So in the code we have a final formula which is I commented there `INDEX( Holiday_master!R2C3:R11C3,MATCH(1,("INDIA"=Holiday_master!R2C2:R11C2)*(43101=Holiday_master!R2C1:R11C1),0),1)`
But its not evaluating as I expected or this could not be the way for evaluation of formula array.

If I execute that formula in that cell manually and on submitting (`ctrl+shift+enter`) it executes properly and returning the value.

So I didnt understand how to do that same from VBA or how to do that Evaluation. I never used Evaluation before

Comment: What is `printf`, is that another function? Btw, are you expecting to return an array?. If that is the case, you should specify it as `Variant` instead of `Double`.

Comment: Does it work if you add `Case Else: location = "INDIA" before `End Select` ? Are you sure there is a 26-Jan-2018 date in column A when India is in column B?

Comment: @L42 -printf is a C function that roughly equates to debug.print.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks. So that is an invalid function? (in VBA)

Comment: @L42 - in vba, yes it is invalid. I'm guessing the OP used it to explain that he was showing the resolved formula.

Comment: @L42 Im really sorry for the delay in replying, its a string.format function I created custom which is for replacing {0},{1},{2}....

Comment: @Jeeped missed to mention my custom function

Comment: @L42 missed to mention my custom function which is added there in question

Answer (score 3):

Convert the formula from xlR1C1 to xlA1 syntax.

```
n = Application.Evaluate(Application.ConvertFormula(formula, xlR1C1, xlA1))
```

Using Evaluate within VBA should be done with xlA1 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with R1C1 itself. The issue was, I specified curly braces there in the formula array which is not required in the case of Evaluate

So here is my modified formula code with error validation also added

```
formula = printf("=IFERROR(INDEX(Holiday_master!R2C3:R{0}C3,MATCH(1,(""{1}""=Holiday_master!R2C2:R{0}C2)*({2}=Holiday_master!R2C1:R{0}C1),0),1),1)", lRow, location, CStr(d))
```

Comment: Yes xlR1C1 syntax is acceptable as long as it is not ambiguous. C5 could mean column E in xlR1C1 but celll(5, 3) in xlA1.

Comment: Yea.. Thats true.. but before calling that function I set the reference style as Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1